# Why does Lon/lat weighted calculation give different result in JavaScript then SQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, math, gps, maps

Based on this site: https://carto.com/blog/center-of-points/ i try to calculate the weighted average for a set of lon/lat points. The site shows the calculation in SQL-code, and i specifically look at the test data set as follows:

```
Data Table

country    lat         lon
-------    --------    ---------
Tonga      -21.1333    -175.2
Tuvalu     -8.53333     179.2167
```

Where the result is:

```
avg_lon    avg_lon_naive    avg_lat
-------    -------------    -------
-177.992   2.00833          -14.9333
```

Now i try to convert this to javascript like this:

```
// Calculate weighted average of points in lat/lon

// mypoint = [lat, lon ]
var mypoint1 = [-21.1333, -175.2];
var mypoint2 = [-8.53333, 179.2167];

//Weighted LON
var zeta = (Math.sin(Math.PI * mypoint1[1] / 180) + Math.sin(Math.PI *         
mypoint2[1] / 180)) / 2;
console.log(zeta);
var xi = (Math.cos(Math.PI * mypoint1[1] / 180) + Math.sin(Math.PI *         
mypoint2[1] / 180)) / 2;
console.log(xi);

var avglon = 180 * Math.atan2(zeta, xi) / Math.PI;
console.log("Average longitude: " + avglon);


//Weighted LAT
var avglat = (mypoint1[0] + mypoint2[0]) / 2;
console.log("Average latitude: " + avglat);
```

Which yields this result:

```
-0.03500355257793927
-0.49141106053653333
Average longitude: -175.92566317222995
Average latitude: -14.833314999999999
Press any key to continue...
```

Why do i get a different result in my JavaScript case? Have i done something wrong in the code? Missed something, some conversion or similar?

Or is there any difference in atan2 or PI in sql vs JavaScript?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

---

Edit: For the LAT calculation I have started to believe that the original post has error. Since the Lat calculation is relatively easy, we can see that:

```
 2 x -14.9333 = 29,8666
```

Which is not the result of the original lat points given

```
 -21.1333 +(-8.53333) = -29.6666299
```

Comment: I guess the 14.9333 is a typo on the webpage....

Comment: I can accept that it is a  typo, but guessing wont do it for me. However, inserting these points:

`   // mypoint = [lat, lon ]
    var mypoint1 = [-30, 60];
    var mypoint2 = [-10, 80]`

Gives lonaverage = -30, and Lat average = 51.26....

**Now what have become the important question for me:**
The assumption for the LON-calculation is that it will cross -over from -178 to 2 degrees etc, if i know that this will never happen, can i just avergage lon in the same way as lat ?

Comment: Edit: Should be: Gives LAT-average = -20, and LON average = 51.26....

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that both methods are not correct. 
On a sphere I'd average the 3D vectors.
In python that would look like:

```
import numpy as np

DEGREE = np.pi/180.
RAD = 1./DEGREE

def lon_lat_naive( inList ):
    return np.mean( inList,axis=0)

def lon_lat_full_vector( inList ):
    vec = [ [ np.cos( lat * DEGREE ) * np.cos( lon * DEGREE ), np.cos(lat* DEGREE ) * np.sin( lon * DEGREE  ), np.sin( lat * DEGREE ) ] for  lon, lat in inList ]
    # ~ print vec
    vec = np.sum( vec, axis=0)
    vec /= np.linalg.norm( vec )
    # ~ print vec
    lat = np.arcsin( vec[2] ) * RAD
    lon = np.arctan2( vec[1], vec[0] ) * RAD
    return [ lon, lat ]


a = np.array( [10, 60 ])
b = np.array( [20, 80 ])

print( lon_lat_naive( np.array( [ a, b ] ) ) )
print( lon_lat_full_vector( np.array( [ a, b ] ) ) )


Tonga = np.array( [ -175.2, -21.1333 ])
Tuvalu = np.array( [ 179.2167, -8.53333 ])

tt = np.array( [Tonga, Tuvalu ] )
print( lon_lat_naive( tt ) )
print( lon_lat_full_vector( tt ) )
```

providing:

```
[15. 70.]
[12.573012941928377, 70.05362118882975]
[  2.00835  -14.833315]
[-178.07333636886855, -14.850146658102775]
```

which is different from both, yours and the web page, but should give you---in the case of the two points---the midpoint of the arc connecting the two.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I also just found this site: https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/354587
 which provide a javascript solution. This solution gives the same result as your calculation ( "me knowing nothing about phyton), and this seems to be correct.

Comment: @otk Good to know. I hoped that the python code is simple enough and, therefore, self explaining. The stuff that I've seen on your linked page even seems to incorporate earth's deviation from a sphere.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I linked the wrong page, my bad: This does not take into account that the earth is not a perfect sphere
https://gist.github.com/tlhunter/0ea604b77775b3e7d7d25ea0f70a23eb

Sorry for all the mess :)

Comment: @otk Ah, ok; that really is the same (if you write the python list comprehension as for-loop). The difference of my `arcsin` vs a second `atan2` actually does not make a difference.